# Set cannot contain duplicates. But it does

Tags: java, android

the [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) Set cannot contain duplicates

however this code works fine:

```
Set<String> vmv = new TreeSet<String>();
vmv.add("a");
vmv.add("a");
System.out.println(vmv.toString());
```

I just added a duplicate. Can someone explain this.

Comment: Please read the Javadoc, specifically what the `add` method does.

Comment: If you mean, that there is a second element in the set, so that vmv.toString() leads to the output "[a, a]"... this isn't the case. With your code there is only one "a" in the set after adding it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `add()` twice with the same value won't add it a second time, check the returned `boolean` and you'll see that the second time it was `false`, or check the set's size to verify that it didn't change after the second time:

```
Set<String> vmv = new TreeSet<String>();

System.out.println(vmv.add("a")); // prints true
System.out.println(vmv.size());   // prints 1

System.out.println(vmv.add("a")); // prints false
System.out.println(vmv.size());   // prints 1
```

Answer (score 2):

From the same page, further down:

> The `add` method adds the specified element to the Set if it's not already present and returns a boolean indicating whether the element was added.

...which is exactly what it's doing.  When you print the final set, you should only see one copy of the "duplicate" element.

Comment: if i understand you correctly.. the duplicate never got entered, it just returned false  ?